# Update datetime values format

Tags: sql-server, datetime, format

I have MsSQL table with these 5000 rows and a column in which some values are currently in a format:

```
Nov 14 2016 2:42PM
Dec 15 2016 5:45PM
```

Is there a way to update those to:

```
2016-11-14 14:42:18.222
2016-12-15 17:45:38.333
```

Or at least the Date Month Year part?

And some values are like this:

```
2014-03-17T10:38:13.300
2014-10-20T13:26:00.267
```

If there is a way to update these too, I would appreciate it.

And some values are OK like this:

```
2016-12-15 14:03:01.444
```

The table looks like this

```
id      stockid attributeid value

1025183 64348   50          Nov 28 2016  1:02PM
1027332 15984   50          2014-10-20T13:26:00.267
1041149 69924   50          Nov 28 2016  1:17PM
1049041 71661   50          2016-12-15 16:54:03.130
```

Data type property of the column is set to varchar.

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: If your column is a varchar they are NOT dates. You should never store dates in a varchar column. This is why we have the date(time) datatype. And the formatting belongs to the consuming application, not the database. My recommendation would be to figure out how to update the datatype to the proper datatype and then this problem goes away.

Comment: It's not problem how future values are gonna look like...the problem is only to those values from November and part of December. So the varchar type is currently fine for me. I post the question just to be sure there is there is no way to write proper update.

Comment: `So the varchar type is currently fine for me. ` - No, it really isn't.  It's never a good idea to store `datetime` values as a `varchar`.  Doing so leads to this exact question that you wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update the existing values, you would need to store them as a DateTime column.

Casting the varchar values to DateTimes is very simple.

```
select CAST('Nov 14 2016 2:42PM' as DATETIME), 
       CAST('2014-03-17T10:38:13.300' as DATETIME)
```

returns

```
  2016-11-14 14:42:00.000   and    2014-03-17 10:38:13.300
```

If you want to update all of the rows in the table you would use this syntax.

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET [ColumnName] = CAST([ColumnName] as DATETIME)
```

You could then alter the table and change the column type from Varchar to DateTime. Though you then may need to modify any code that accesses this table column and expects a varchar.

Comment: i will try that

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide you with an Update Statement. I'd also recommend changing the column type to DateTime

Comment: update stockattributesvalues set value=CAST('2014-03-17T10:38:13.300' as datetime)

I am not making it right

Comment: if you that update statement in your last comment, without using a primary key or some other where clause, you will update all records in that table with that same value.  Don't do that.    Use update stockattributesvalues set value=CAST(value as datetime)